# Application menu accelerators and OpenFileHandler not working in Swing application

Tags: java, macos, swing

I'm trying to add proper support for OS X in my Java 8 Swing application. To do this I'm using the com.apple:AppleJavaExtensions:1.4 package from maven.

I initialise the menu bar using the following code:

```
Application application = Application.getApplication();

JMenu fileMenu = new JMenu("File");
JMenuItem openMenuItem = new JMenuItem("Open...");
openMenuItem.addActionListener(action -> openFileDialog());
openMenuItem.setAccelerator(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_O, InputEvent.META_MASK));
fileMenu.add(openMenuItem);

JMenuBar mainMenuBar = new JMenuBar();
mainMenuBar.add(fileMenu);
application.setDefaultMenuBar(mainMenuBar);
```

This works just fine the first time, without any Swing windows opened. However, when one file is opened (and a Swing window is created), the shortcut stops working. Pressing CMD+O still highlights the menu item, but the action isn't executed. Using the mouse to select the 'Open...' menu item *does* work. I'm guessing the Swing window is somehow stealing the event (but the menu is still highlighted when the key combo is pressed.. weird).

When the file open dialog (that openFileDialog() shows) is cancelled, the menu accelerator will keep working. So it is definitely related to the Swing window being opened when a file is opened.

Another problem with opening files with OS X is that the following code never shows 'foo':

```
application.setOpenFileHandler(e -> System.out.println("foo"));
```

This code is executed in main() (which returns almost instantly, after creating the menu bar I mentioned earlier). The file handler isn't ever called; not when dropping a file onto the dock icon, nor when double clicking a file and opening it with my application.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Check for any missing/empty exception handlers.

Comment: I confirm that this doesn't work as expected. To make the hotkey work requires using jframe.setJMenuBar(), which defeats the purpose of using application.setDefaultMenuBar(). I checked for uncaught exception using Thread.setDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler() and didn't see any.

Answer (score 1):

If your app doesn't have many Frames then this could be a workaround.

```
setJMenuBar(menuBar);
final Dimension invisible = new Dimension(0, 0);
menuBar.setSize(invisible);
menuBar.setMaximumSize(invisible);
menuBar.setPreferredSize(invisible);
menuBar.setMinimumSize(invisible);
```

Answer (score 0):

Apparently the OpenFileHandler does nothing unless your Java application is running from an application bundle with an Info.plist that specifies appropriate CFBundleDocumentTypes. Here's an example of what it should look like:

http://www.qtcentre.org/wiki/index.php?title=Opening_documents_in_the_Mac_OS_X_Finder

I worked around the menu accelerator not working by simply registering a KeyEventDispatcher to the KeyboardFocusManager on each of the Swing windows, and manually invoking the appropriate ActionListeners when the correct KeyEvent is caught. Very very ugly, but it works. I'm still wondering why this is necessary.